# Is there a way to get a good looking starry skybox to use in Apple's SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit, skybox

I'm writing an astronomy application using Apple's SceneKit and want to provide a skybox of stars to surround a planet.

I have found a large JPEG (8192x4096) with suitable content but my "camera" field of view (10 degrees) magnifies the skybox image background enough to cause serious loss of resolution.  In short, it doesn't look good .. here's a screenshot showing blurry stars:

https://ramsaycons.com/screenshots/SkyBoxRes.png

One solution for greater fidelity would be, I imagine, to use a resolution independent 'material' image like a PDF, but SceneKit doesn't support PDF 'materials'.

Or, I could find, or build, a better or bigger image for the skybox material.  For example, a (32768x16384) would look better, at the cost of a massive image ~ the 'small' one I'm using now is nearly 8MB already.

Another option would be to move closer to the planet and widen the field of view, but I don't want to move the camera so close (specifically, because I want it 'above' geosynchronous objects in my model).

This code-less question feels not quite appropriate for StackOverflow, but my reading of related Q&A's here reveals a knowledge of clever SceneKit tricks I wouldn't have thought off .. maybe there's a trick for me out there!